# chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished - console.log not executed

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have this code to create a devtools panel in a chrome extension. For learning proupose I want to inspect network requests of a certain website and get the body of them.

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create('Spotify test', '', '/index.html');

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener( (request) => {
  //console.log(request);
  if(request.method === 'GET' && request.response.status === '206' ){
    console.log(request);
    request.getContent( (content, encoding) => {
      console.log(content, encoding);
    });
  }
});
```

The problem is that the `if(request.method === 'GET' && request.response.status === '206' )` will not be executed, I'm able to log the request object of the callback only if I put it outside the statement. I want to log only requests that are using the `GET` method and that have the `206` status code. As I read in the documentation, on the request object I can use the `getContent()` method to get the body of the response, is this right? Is there any error in the code that will prevent to the `console.log()` to be fired?

NB: I'm using the devtools console that is opened by clicking the inspect menu voice inside the panel I've added.

Comment: The only other place is `Inspect views` in the extension's card in `chrome://extensions` page.

Comment: do you mean the same voice that open the background script inspector?

Comment: There'll be a separate item for devtools panel, probably.

Comment: Already checked, but nothing is logged. Only when I remove the if the console will log request

Answer (score 1):

request.request.method instead of request.method